# How can I get the method (or linenumber) where the value of a variable changed?

Tags: javascript, html, web, firebug, listener

How can I get the method (or linenumber) where the value of a variable changed?

My problem is, that I have a big part of a sourccode, where a value of a variable change. But I don't know where. (The source code isn't written by me)

I've tried to debug the code with firebug, but firebug crashed. So I think, that I have to set an listener on this variable. But how can i get the part of the sorucecode where its called?

Thanks for your ideas

Comment: AFAIK there is no any debugger which can track variable mutations, and this feature is not available on language level, so your task will be huge pain. The only way I can suggest is to set breakpoint in place where you sure that var already changed and then traverse back in call stack.

Comment: Well I didn't find any other solution, but I've found the part in the source code where the value has changed. Might somebody knows a solution for the Question, would be interesting (and interesting for the googlers, too)